# Problem with starting GUI mode in Ubuntu Server

Tags: startup, lightdm

Well I have installed the Server version of Ubuntu 12.04. Since I was only getting terminal, I installed the desktop package and executed these commands in the following order:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get update
```

After installing desktop package, though I got a few failure errors but it got installed. I rebooted but still I cannot see the GUI mode,again landing in terminal. Tried to execute **startx** command but its only showing a white screen with a black background. Any insight will be deeply appreciated from this Linux beginner.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between server and desktop is only the GUI. Since it sounds like this is your first go I highly recommend downloading a desktop version and reinstalling you will save yourself a lot of hassle.

Comment: Well I am kinda using a VM in the cloud which has a predefined OS and that is Ubuntu Server. It would be really helpful if you can suggest me how to get the GUI mode in server, i.e. as I have mentioned above with installing desktop package.